# What are the options, settings and exceptions for HessianProxyFactory?

Tags: java, hessian

I can't find javadoc for Hessian lib. I want to know how to configure and full usage of Hessian client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is at [hessian.caucho.com](http://hessian.caucho.com/), but Hessian's not commonly used any more, it seems to have withered on the vine.

You could have a look at [Spring's Hessian client support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/caucho/HessianProxyFactoryBean.html), either to use it, or to give you an idea of how to use the Hessian API. This, at least, is well-documented.

Comment: only specification of protocol and the very simple usage example

Comment: @ii2: It wouldn't been helpful if you'd mentioned that to begin with.  Anyway, see edited answer.

Comment: thanks, indeed I'm going to use Hessian Client with Spring 3. and I found there setReadTimeOut() method which I was searching.